# Undirected link in package: kitz, library:bayesnet

Tags: graphics, tikz-arrows

I want a undirected-dashed-link rather than an dashed-arrow between `$phi$` and `$\sigma_y$` for the this network. I could not figure out how to do it.

[image]

Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikz{ %
        \node[latent] (phi) {$\phi$};
        \node[latent, above=of phi] (f) {$f$};
        \node[obs, left=of f] (y) {$\bf{y}$};
        \node[latent, below =of y] (sigma) {$\sigma_y$};
        \edge {phi} {f};
        \edge {f, sigma} {y};
        \plate[inner sep=0.25cm, xshift=-0.12cm, yshift=0.12cm] {plate3} {(phi) (f) (y) (sigma)} {W}; %
        \edge [dashed] {phi} {sigma};
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the option `-` (arrow without arrow tips) to the edge in question. This overwrites the default setting.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikz{ %
        \node[latent] (phi) {$\phi$};
        \node[latent, above=of phi] (f) {$f$};
        \node[obs, left=of f] (y) {$\bf{y}$};
        \node[latent, below =of y] (sigma) {$\sigma_y$};
        \edge {phi} {f};
        \edge {f, sigma} {y};
        \plate[inner sep=0.25cm, xshift=-0.12cm, yshift=0.12cm] {plate3} {(phi) (f) (y) (sigma)} {W}; %
        \edge [dashed,-] {phi} {sigma};
        % add here ---^
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]